# Unable to make custom copy event listener, bound to an element, work properly

Tags: javascript

I have added a custom event listener to copy/cut of text from an element (say elementId). Now when I copy from elementId and paste on word the functionality works fine.
But when I copy from the elementId and paste on notepad, the paste doesn't work. By doesn't work I mean nothing is pasted at all.

```
document.getElementById(config.editorEl).addEventListener('copy', function(event) {
    const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const content = range.cloneContents();
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(content);
    $(div)
    .find('.remove_this_class')
    .contents()
    .unwrap();
    event.clipboardData.setData('text/html', div.innerHTML);
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Summary: The custom copy/cut handler doesn't work properly.

- Copy - paste on word (works correctly)
- Copy - paste on notepad(Nothing gets pasted at all)
- Copy - paste on url bar (Nothing gets
  pasted at all)

Comment: I think you may need to remove `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: But don't you think that event.clipboardData.setData() shall be enough ?

Comment: I made a snippet of the code, and in firefox at least, it was the `event.preventDefault()` that was stopping the code from working

Comment: [event.clipboardData.setData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) doesn't actually put the passed data to the clipboard, it just defines what data to put to clipboard when the action triggered the event takes place.

Comment: @Teemu that would explain it.

Comment: Removing the preventDefault() reverts to the basic copy-paste functionality. I want to perform the additional operation that I added above preventDefault() too.

Comment: It might be that you're not doing everything needed to copy to clipboard? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

Comment: Its everything. The issue occurs in case of 'text/html'. If i use 'text/plain' everything is copied properly but the issue here is that other span , bold , italics tags are displayed as text.

Comment: Don't use setData? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write